# php mysql return wrong boolean result

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following query :

```
'SELECT Active FROM tbUsers WHERE Id=55'
```

The Id is unique and I need just to know the status of the user if he's active yes or no. The Column Active is set as boolean in Mysql

When I tried to return the result like the following (using another php function) :

```
$result = $this->selectRow($db,"tbClass","Active","Id='$Id'");
if($result) { return "ok" ; } else { return "nok" ;)
```

it returns 'ok' on both cases.
Any idea what's wrong with it ?

Here is the other function :

```
public function selectRow($db,$tableName,$field,$where) {
        if($where == "") {
            $query = "SELECT $field FROM $tableName";
        }
        else
        { $query = "SELECT $field FROM $tableName WHERE $where"; }

        $result=$db->Qry($query);


        if ($result) {
            $no_of_rows =  $db->TotRows($result);
            if($no_of_rows == 1) {
                return $result;
            }
            if($no_of_rows == 0) {
                return '';
            }
            if($no_of_rows < 0) {
                die('Invalid query: ' . $sender ."(".$query  ."): ".mysql_errno().": ". mysql_error());
                return '';
            }
        } 
        else {
            die('Invalid query: ' . $sender .": " .$query.": ". mysql_errno().": ". mysql_error());
            return '';
        }
    }
```

Qry Function is the following :

```
function Qry($sql) {
    if($result = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql) ) {
        return $result;
    }
    else 
    {
        $err = "Error: ".$sql. " :: ". mysqli_error;
        die("$err");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `$db` an instance of? Also, you said "OK" is being returned in both instances, but you've only given one instance, `Id = 55`. What's the other instance and which should return OK?

Comment: You have a class in $db that is not a standard class of PHP, it's somthing you developed, so I can't really know what Qry or ToRows does. If I need to guess, ToRows returns the array of the result, so you need to check if count($result) == 1 and not $result.

Comment: right i have a class db which does :  Execute Query and Record Count

Comment: @Styphon : if Modify the Active Column to true(1) the result is the same if that column is set to False(0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change this condition .

```
 $result=$db->Qry($query);
```

> always return you query object

Just remove this condition and

You need to `count number of affected row`

```
<?php

public function selectRow($db, $tableName, $field, $where) {
    if ($where == "") {
        $query = "SELECT $field FROM $tableName";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT $field FROM $tableName WHERE $where";
    }

    $result = $db->Qry($query);



    $no_of_rows = $db->TotRows($result);
    if ($no_of_rows == 1) {
        return $result;
    }
    if ($no_of_rows == 0) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    if ($no_of_rows < 0) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . $sender . "(" . $query . "): " . mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error());
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: i agree with you that's an object but how to return the value of the object not the object itself

Comment: use  `$result->fetch_object()` to get object

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so `$result` is a [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object.
You might want to fetch the first row of that result and return the desired column.

Replace

```
return $result;
```

with

```
return $result->fetch_assoc()[$field];
```

Comment: I have added  this : if(is_array($result))  echo "array"; And it does show anything so  it's NOt an array.

Comment: please have a look in main block to see what the QRY function does